# SVT-AV1 Emscripten build

Tags: c++, cmake, ffmpeg, emscripten

I am trying to build [svt-av1](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1) v1.4.1 for [ffmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) with [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/) 3.1.32. I have followed [Build-Guide](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/master/Docs/Build-Guide.md) and ended up with the following command:

```bash
cd Build

BUILD_DIR=/home/jozefchutka/ffmpeg-wasm/build/
TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$EMSDK/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake

emmake cmake .. -G"Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$BUILD_DIR -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$TOOLCHAIN_FILE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD=On -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-O3 -I/home/jozefchutka/ffmpeg-wasm/build/include -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -msimd128"

emmake make -j
```

however the process fails on:

```
...
[ 95%] Building C object Source/App/EncApp/CMakeFiles/SvtAv1EncApp.dir/EbTime.c.o
[ 96%] Linking C executable ../../../../Bin/Release/SvtAv1EncApp.js
emcc: error: noexecstack: No such file or directory ("noexecstack" was expected to be an input file, based on the commandline arguments provided)
make[2]: *** [Source/App/EncApp/CMakeFiles/SvtAv1EncApp.dir/build.make:213: ../Bin/Release/SvtAv1EncApp.js] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:574: Source/App/EncApp/CMakeFiles/SvtAv1EncApp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Generated build.make and link.txt which contains some relevant info.

```
211: ../Bin/Release/SvtAv1EncApp.js: Source/App/EncApp/CMakeFiles/SvtAv1EncApp.dir/link.txt
212:    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/home/jozefchutka/ffmpeg-wasm/modules/svtav1/Build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_8) "Linking C executable ../../../../Bin/Release/SvtAv1EncApp.js"
213:    cd /home/jozefchutka/ffmpeg-wasm/modules/svtav1/Build/Source/App/EncApp && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/SvtAv1EncApp.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
```

```
/home/jozefchutka/ffmpeg-wasm/modules/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc -O3 -I/home/jozefchutka/ffmpeg-wasm/build/include -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -msimd128 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -z noexecstack -z relro -z now @CMakeFiles/SvtAv1EncApp.dir/objects1.rsp -o ../../../../Bin/Release/SvtAv1EncApp.js @CMakeFiles/SvtAv1EncApp.dir/linklibs.rsp
```

As I am not fluent in c/c++ and related build stack, I am not sure if the problem is my build misconfiguration, svt-av1 sources or emscripten.

Please help me resolve the issue or at least identify the cause, so I can continue in relevant issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your reference, the line that adds those linker flags is here: https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/v1.4.1/CMakeLists.txt#L211

```
if(UNIX)
    if(APPLE)
        ...
    else()
        set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -z noexecstack -z relro -z now")
    endif()
endif()
```

Since this is setting a variable (and variables are scoped to CMake directories), this variable must be applying to a target in the same or deeper directory scope, and the error is happening because these linker flags are not supported by `emcc` (the Emscripten compiler and linker). The reference docs for Emscripten's commandline flags can be found here: https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#command-line-syntax. I have also found this resource useful for finding out which option flags are for compiling and which are for linking: https://emsettings.surma.technology/.

Looking through the target definitions in SVT-AV1, you'll find that executables are defined in the `Source/App` folder: [Source/App/DecApp/CMakeLists.txt](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/v1.4.1/Source/App/DecApp/CMakeLists.txt) and [Source/App/EncApp/CMakeLists.txt](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/v1.4.1/Source/App/EncApp/CMakeLists.txt). Those executables get added by default.

See [this line in the root CMakeLists.txt](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/v1.4.1/CMakeLists.txt#L145) (notice that the default is `ON`):

```
option(BUILD_APPS "Build Enc and Dec Apps" ON)
```

And [these lines](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/v1.4.1/CMakeLists.txt#L514) that `add_subdirectory` the apps folders:

```
if(BUILD_APPS AND BUILD_ENC)
    add_subdirectory(Source/App/EncApp)
endif()
if(BUILD_APPS AND BUILD_DEC)
    add_subdirectory(Source/App/DecApp)
endif()
```

So if you don't need those apps to be built for your purposes, you can stop them from being built by adding `-DBUILD_APPS=OFF` in your configure command.

If you *do* need those to be built for your purposes, [raise an issue ticket](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/issues) or implement changes in a Merge Request to somehow resolve that issue when the Emscripten toolchain is being used. You can use the `EMSCRIPTEN` CMake variable, which the Emscripten CMake toolchain file defines to do the platform check.

Comment: Thanks this was very useful. I have eventually added `-DBUILD_APPS=OFF` which solved the issue. Also answered my own question here around the same time of your response

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by including an extra flag `-DBUILD_APPS=OFF`, which caused that the problematic line is not executed.